# native WebRTC with Visual Studio build error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build, webrtc

I've succcessfully build native WebRTC and got webrtc.lib file in result. Then i was trying to setup Visual Studio 2017 simple project to use webrtc and I pointed include and library directory and also in dependencies added webrtc.lib. For some reason just simple code like this:

```
#define WEBRTC_WIN

#include<iostream>
#include<api/mediastreaminterface.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    return 0;
}
```

generates around 100 errors mainly about min and max functions and rtc::rtc namespace which is weird looks like somehow all rtc::x calls it interprets as rtc::rtc:x for example

```
Error   C2039   'scoped_refptr': is not a member of 'rtc::rtc'  webrtctest  c:\libwebrtc\webrtc\src\api\mediastreaminterface.h  287
```

I've tried to download already compiled versions with different include files but got same errors. Also there is an error saying

```
Error   C2059   syntax error: 'namespace'   webrtctest  c:\libwebrtc\webrtc\src\rtc_base\messagequeue.h 33
```

which is pointing to this line:

```
namespace rtc {
```

I've downloaded latest branch-69, and my windows sdk version is 10.0.17134.0

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to make it work. I had to add `#define NOMINMAX` on top of everything because there were macros inside of windows.h with same name.